# I would like to identify the correct code for the button highlighted in yellow

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, checkbox, selenium-chromedriver

How can I figure this out? I am new to Selenium.

[image]

```html
<div id="InVivoVitroWorkcheckboxDiv" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <div class="btn btn-default"> <input class="vivovitrocls" type="checkbox" name="SelectedInVivoVitroWork" value="In Vivo Animals"> In Vivo Animals<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></div>
  <div class="btn btn-default"> <input class="vivovitrocls" type="checkbox" name="SelectedInVivoVitroWork" value="In Vivo Humans"> In Vivo Humans<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></div>
  <div class="btn btn-default"> <input class="vivovitrocls" type="checkbox" name="SelectedInVivoVitroWork" value="In Vitro Work"> In Vitro Work<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></div>
  <div class="btn btn-default"> <input class="vivovitrocls" type="checkbox" name="SelectedInVivoVitroWork" value="NA"> N/A<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry if the post is confusion. I am trying to set click on the 'In Vitro Work' button as attached but I am unable to do that. When I tried obj.FindElementById("InVivoVitroWorkcheckboxDiv").Click         it clicks on the "In Vivo Humans" button but I would like to click on the "In Vitro Work". Sorry if this is not in the correct format. Thanks for your help in this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are clicking **In Vivo Humans** is because, you have not identified any of the 4 checkbox instead yo have identified the parent Div containing all 4 checkbox. Since In Vivo Humans is in middle of div, its clicking there.

To click any of the checkbox correctly you have to write unique locator for that. For example if you want to click **in Vitro work**, ypu can write unique xpath locator:

**VBA:**

```
Dim obj as new webdriver
obj.start "Chrome"
obj.get "file:///C:/Users/rahul/OneDrive/Desktop/abc.html"
obj.FindElementByXPath("//div[input[@value='In Vitro Work']]").Click
```

**Python**

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('..\drivers\chromedriver')
driver.get("file:///C:/Users/rahul/OneDrive/Desktop/abc.html")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='In Vitro Work']").click()
```

**Java**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\user\\rahul\\chromedriver.exe");  
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("file:///C:/Users/rahul/OneDrive/Desktop/abc.html");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='In Vitro Work']")).click();
```

**output:**

[image]

You can go through below post to know more about locating element uniquely using selenium webdriver.
https://www.browserstack.com/guide/locators-in-selenium

Comment: Hi Rahul, thanks very much for taking your time to answer me. Much appreciated! Thanks for helping me with the locators. I think the issue even when I get to the correct location I get a the below error message  - Selenium error element click intercepted: Element<input class="vivovitrocls" type="checkbox" name="SelectedInVivoVitroWork" value="In Vitro Work">is not clickable at point (304,507). Other element would receive the click: <div class=btn btn-default">...</div>

Comment: I have tried putting a wait for the page to fully load as well and maximised the window, but everything loads fine, not sure where I am going wrong

Comment: @Tikku As your input tag is inside Div tag it might be throwing error. Can you wrap your input tag inside div as below:
//div[input[@value='In Vitro Work']]
I have updated VBA code try now.

Comment: that's just brilliant buddy! It worked like a charm and helped me solve some of the other buttons as well. You just solved my big headache. My best wishes for you in anything you do. Thanks very much, have a lovely day! regards,

Comment: By the way,I am not sure how to close this thread and this is resolved. Cheers

Comment: You don't close a thread.  However you can upvote if it solves your issue. Thanks a lot cheers !! See below link:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96281/how-to-close-a-question-in-stackoverflow-com

Comment: @Tikku can you please accept the answer. Thanks!!!

"If others have answered your question and you found them helpful, upvote them and accept the most helpful answer by clicking on the checkmark next to the question."

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get(r"C:\tmp\seltest.htm")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='InVivoVitroWorkcheckboxDiv']/div[2]/input").click()
```

Output (no classes)

[image]

Comment: sorry mate , first of all he is asking for solution using VBA ( see tags) and also he wants to select InVitro Work checkbox instead of Vivo work.

Comment: Thank you @Mike67 for taking your time to help me but I am working on VBA and unfortunately I get the following error 'Selenium error element click intercepted' even when I tried to use your XPath.